# Error building alsa-sys and libudev-sys for Bevy

Tags: rust, build, bevy

I am trying to get started with bevy, I have set up the environment as suggested by the bevy book including using the nightly tool chain. However, when I try to build bevy I get the messages:

```
error: failed to run custom build command for `alsa-sys v0.3.1`
error: failed to run custom build command for `libudev-sys v0.1.4`
```

my `cargo.toml` is:

```
[package]
name = "Bevy_1"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html
[profile.dev]
opt-level = 1

[profile.dev.package."*"]
opt-level = 3

[dependencies]
bevy = {version = "0.10", features = ["dynamic_linking"]}
```

and my `rust-toolchain.toml` is:

```
[toolchain]
channel = "nightly"
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Are you one linux and have you installed the [required dependencies](https://github.com/bevyengine/bevy/blob/main/docs/linux_dependencies.md)?

Comment: @frankenapps thanks, I was just following the book and hadn't checked github so I missed it. Compiles like a dream,

Comment: @frankenapps can you post that as an answer so I can accept it? Lets the question be marked as answered and gets you some rep.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to install the [required dependencies](https://github.com/bevyengine/bevy/blob/main/docs/linux_dependencies.md) for your linux distribution.

This is also covered in the bevy book for all major (desktop) operating systems over [here](https://bevyengine.org/learn/book/getting-started/setup/#install-os-dependencies).